# Android SDK and fresh install

Tags: android

I'm looking into buying an Android phone and I'd like to do some development on it as well. Is it possible to perform a fresh clean install on any Android device via the SDK? In other words, is it possible to remove the preloaded OS (i.e. with additional provider software) and install the standard Android OS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a vanilla Android device to do development, I'd pick up a [Nexus S](http://www.google.com/phone/detail/nexus-s) or other development phone.  It's your best and easiest bet.  You could root your device and find a ROM that someone has built from stock.

Comment: I'd love to pick up a Nexus S, but in practice it's a lot cheaper for me to get one on AT&T (through a family plan). It looks like the Samsung Captivate is the best option there. So in general, developers that don't have a Nexus One or Nexus S have to develop over the shell that their service provider forces on them?

Comment: That should be fine.  I believe it is now at 2.2 and just stick with the stock build.

Answer (score 0):

No. The Android SDK is meant for developing Android user-level applications/services, not for developing the Android OS.

That answers your question, but not what you want to do.

What you want to do is better answered by rgmills.

Comment: So, what about those in the community who choose to work on aspects of the operating system itself, or does that not occur? Or if a developer would like to work on an app that makes use of an update to the OS that hasn't yet been released by their service provider?

Comment: Depends on the type of changes you want to make. The more low-level the change, the less likely the chance that your store-bought Android phone can be modified appropriately and still stay under warranty. Many of the default installed apps can't be replaced on consumer Android phones. If you want to modify stuff at the OS level, then you'll need to root the device AFAIK (or get a Nexus).